# how to reproduce the command "rpm -qa | grep xxx" via script

Tags: bash

How can I reproduce the command `rpm -qa | grep xxx` with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "RPM is installed?" name
rpm -qa | grep $name
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: When I execute list additional lines:

Comment: when I execute, after response print additional lines: "rqq.sh: line 3: /home/paul: is a directory - rqq.sh: line 4: /home/paul/: is a directory". My OS CentOS 6.4 bash 4.1.2(1) x86_64

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the script like this:

```
script.sh 'foo*'
```

you need to quote `$name` to make sure its value is passed to `grep` unexpanded:

```
read -p "RPM is installed?" name
rpm -qa | grep "$name"
```

Comment: Thanks chepner. Now run